# OWIN app.use vs app.run vs app.map

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, katana

What's the difference among `app.use`, `app.run`, `app.map` in [Owin](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana)? When to use what? It's not straightforward when reading the documentation.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`app.use` inserts a middleware into the pipeline which requires you to call the next middleware by calling next.Invoke().

`app.run` inserts a middleware without a next, so it just runs.

With `app.map` you can map paths, which get evaluated at runtime, per request, to run certain middleware only if the request path matches the pattern you mapped.

See docs for [`use` and `run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/owin.appbuilderuseextensions.run(v=vs.113).aspx) and [`map`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn337263(v=vs.111).aspx) for more details

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with a request we use IApplicationBuilder. And we have four methods available to interact with a request:

- Use
- Run
- Map
- MapWhen

These are called **Request Delegates**.

**Use**:

> Adds a middleware to the application pipeline and it can either pass
> the request to next delegate or it can end the request (short- circuit
> request pipeline). It is the most commonly used method to interact
> with middleware.

**Map**

> We use Map to connect a request path with another middleware. That
> middleware can use any of the other mentioned request delegates.

**MapWhen**

> Behaves almost the same as Map except that we can specify the detailed
> condition by using a HttpContext object. We could check for URL,
> headers, query strings, cookies, etc).

**Run**

> Generate a response and short-circuit the
> request

Please also read this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/overview-of-middleware-in-asp-net-core/) for more information.